# When does react component re-render its children components?

Tags: reactjs, components, state

I am new to reactjs and the tutorial that I am following taught me that when state of a component changes, it re-renders along with its children component. I was about to simulate that on a simpler example [look at the first code block], however, when I tried to do the same on a complex use case it does not works [look at the second code block]. Here is the simpler example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

type BannerProps = {
  msg: string,
  count: number
}

class Banner extends Component<BannerProps> {
  render(): React.ReactNode {
    return <p>{this.props.msg} {this.props.count}</p>
  }
}

type AppState = {
  item?: {
    msg: string,
    count: number
  }
};

class App extends Component<{}, AppState> {
  state: AppState = {
    item: undefined
  };

  onBtnClicked(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>): void {
    this.setState(s => ({
      item: {
        msg: s.item ? s.item.msg + "clicked" : "clicked",
        count: s.item ? s.item.count + 1 : 0
      }
    }));
  }

  render(): React.ReactNode {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.item && (<Banner msg={this.state.item.msg} count={this.state.item.count} />)}
        <button onClick={e => this.onBtnClicked(e)}>Click Me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[screenshot of the first codeblock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkQd3.png)

Now look at the code example I tried myself and got stuck. You can look at the whole code base if you want: [Github](https://github.com/Moon422/SpmsApp.git)

```
import { Component, ReactNode } from "react";
import { HOST_URL } from "../../../global";
import AddSchool from "./add-school";
import EditSchool from "./edit-remove-school";

export class School {
    schoolName?: string;
    schoolCode?: string;
}

export class SchoolWithID extends School {
    id?: number;
    deanName?: string;
}

type AddEditRemoveSchoolProps = {
    userToken: string
};

type AddEditRemoveSchoolState = {
    schools: SchoolWithID[]
};

export default class AddEditRemoveSchool extends Component<AddEditRemoveSchoolProps, AddEditRemoveSchoolState> {
    state: AddEditRemoveSchoolState = { schools: [] };

    onSchoolAdded(school: SchoolWithID) {
        this.setState(s => ({
            schools: [...s.schools, school]
        }));
    }

    render(): ReactNode {
        return (
            <div className="containter-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col">
                        <AddSchool userToken={this.props.userToken} onSchoolAddedCallback={s => this.onSchoolAdded(s)} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                        Edit School { /* to be implemented*/ }
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    School list { /* to be implemented*/}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Definition of AddSchool Component is in the 3rd code block.

```
import React, { Component, ReactNode } from "react";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { HOST_URL } from "../../../global";
import { School, SchoolWithID } from "./school";


type AddSchoolProps = {
    userToken: string,
    onSchoolAddedCallback: (school: SchoolWithID) => void,
};

export default class AddSchool extends Component<AddSchoolProps> {
    addSchoolFormSubmit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const formdata = new FormData(e.target as HTMLFormElement);

        if (formdata) {
            const school: School = {
                schoolName: formdata.get("schoolName") as string,
                schoolCode: formdata.get("schoolCode") as string
            };

            const url = `${HOST_URL}/school/create`;
            const headers = {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${this.props.userToken}`
            };

            fetch(url, {
                headers: headers,
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(school)
            }).then(res => {
                if (res.ok) {
                    console.log("Addedd");
                    res.json().then(res => this.props.onSchoolAddedCallback(res))
                } else {
                    res.text().then(err => console.log(err));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    render(): ReactNode {
        return (
            <>
                <h2>Add New School</h2>
                <form onSubmit={e => this.addSchoolFormSubmit(e)}>
                    <label htmlFor="schoolName" className="form-label">School Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="schoolName" id="schoolName" className="form-control mb-2" placeholder="School Name" required />
                    
                    <label htmlFor="schoolCode" className="form-label">School Code:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="schoolCode" id="schoolCode" className="form-control mb-2" placeholder="School Code" required />

                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="w-100 btn btn-danger" />
                </form>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

AddSchool component displays a form that takes input for new school and adds the school to the database. It is child to the AddEditRemoveSchool component. AddSchool component also takes a callback function as prop that is called the form is submit. I am using that callback to lift the newly created school up to the parent, that is the AddEditRemoveSchool component, and update its state. When the state in the parent component is updated, my basic instinct was that it will re-render along with the AddSchool component and the input text will be cleared out. But it is does not happen. Please let me what is happening? How can I make AddSchool component re-render following reactjs best practices?

Pardon me if I am asking a lame question. I am a novice in frontend development and have limited knowledge about HTML and CSS. I more into backend stuffs. Also, I could have used direct DOM manipulation, somewhere on the internet , I read manipulating DOM directly is bad practice and not react way of doing stuffs.

I hope you can understand my issue and thanks for helping me out. Peace.

I was expecting the AddSchool component to re-render when parent component re-renders upon state change and as a result the text fields to clear out.

Comment: Rerendering doesn't necessarily have to clear the inputs

Comment: @Konrad, then how should I achieve that? Should do DOM manipulation in the onSubmit callback of the form and set empty string as value of the input fields? It does the work, but is it a react good practice? What should be the ideal way to do that?